# Why this website fail under IE?

Tags: html, css

I have big problem with my website: http://hiperteksty.org
with safari and firefox browser works good but under IE layout look bad.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it will not help future visitors


Comment: It looks fine in IE9.  What issue are you seeing?  Your Logo image is not found, but that's true in both browsers.

Answer (score 9):

Before I even look, I'm going to guess you didn't start your file with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Now I look at it. What do you know, I was right!

Well, sort of. you *do* have a DOCTYPE, but it's invalid. Try just using the one I listed above.